# How can I pull variable value from the child component in React

Tags: reactjs, components

I got "Count" component which is the child component.
In the Parent component I got variable calls "initial" which increment every 5 seconds. How can I pull the "initial" value from the child component using React?

Parent component:

```
function App() {
  var initial = 0
  setInterval(function(){ initial++ }, 5000);
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <Login initial={initial}/>
        <button onClick={()=>(this.forceUpdate())}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child component:

```
const Count = ({initial}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useInitialState(

   //How should I implement the useInitialState so that it will pull the 
   //initial value from the parent every 5 sec

  );
  return (
    <div>
        {count}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Maybe use a context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get initial value from Parent Component, you need to store the initial value in state and update the state every 5 secs. By this it will automatically rerender your child component and you will be able to get the initial value passed through prop.

```
function App() {
  const [initial, setInitial] = useState(0);
  setInterval(function(){ setInitial(initial++) }, 5000);
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Count initial={initial}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for you answer. But I already know this way. I need find a way to pull variable value from the parent component to the child component.

Comment: This is how, you can get value frm Parent Component to Child Component. Did u mean from Child to Parent?

Comment: I asked this question. I know there are better way so do this but I looking for a way to pull the initial value from the child component.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer to pull initial value from the child component.

- Create a callback in the parent component which takes in the data
  needed as a parameter.
- Pass this callback as a prop to the child component.
- Send data from the child component using the callback.

Parent Component

```
function App() {
  const getInitial = () => {} // initial value for getInitial 

  setGetInitialMethod = (newMethod) => {
    getInitial = newMethod;
  }
  var initial = 0
  setInterval(function(){ initial++ }, 5000);
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <Login initial={initial}/>
        <button onClick={()=>(this.forceUpdate())}>click</button>
        <Count setGetInitialMethod={setGetInitialMethod}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child Component

```
const Count = ({initial, setGetInitialMethod}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useInitialState(
     setGetInitialMethod(getInitial);
  );
  const getInitial() => {
    alert('clicked');
  }
  return (
    <div>
        {count}
    </div>
  );
}
```